# How to get only list of items without geometry from OGC services?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, ogc

How can I get list of items from WMS or WFS services? I want to fill dropdown list, so I do not need geometries. I need only JSON list of items.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=topp:states&properyname=STATE_NAME`? Save the response on disk and open with text editor, it is not a program. There is some issue with the MIME type.

Comment: getting via ajax request

Comment: @user30184 - this was the solution for me thanks!, heads up there's a type, it should be `propertyname`

Answer (score 1):

A `GetCapabilities` request to the relevant service will return an XML document containing details of all the layers/feature types.